# How to user Perl to find all instances of strings that match a regexp?

Tags: regex, perl

How to user Perl to find and print all strings that match a regexp?

The following only finds the first match.

```
$text="?Adsfsadfgaasdf.
?Bafadfdsaadsfadsf.
xcxvfdgfdg";

if($text =~ m/\\?([^\.]+\.)/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

### EDIT1: `/g` doesn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$text="?Adsfsadfgaasdf.
?Bafadfdsaadsfadsf.
xcxvfdgfdg";

if($text =~ m/\\?([^\.]+\.)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}

$ ./test.pl 
?Adsfsadfgaasdf.
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question as a way to reply to comments and answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the `/g` modifier does not use capture groups for multiple matches. You need to either iterate over the matches in scalar context, or catch the returned list in list context. For example:

```
use v5.10; # required for say()
$text="?Adsfsadfgaasdf.
?Bafadfdsaadsfadsf.
xcxvfdgfdg";

while ($text =~ /\?([^.]+\.)/g) {  # scalar context
    say $1;
}
for ($text =~ /\?[^.]+\./g) {     # list context
    say;               # match is held in $_
}
```

Note in the second case, I skipped the parens, because in list context the whole match is returned if there are no parens. You may add parens to select part of the string.

Your version, using `if`, uses scalar context, which saves the position of the most recent match, but does not continue. A way to see what happens is:

```
if($text =~ m/\?([^\.]+\.)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
say "Rest of string: ", substr $text, pos;
```

`pos` gives the position of the most recent match.

Comment: @flesk I suppose I should have written "the most recent match" instead of "the last match".

Comment: Why in `for ($text =~ /?[^.]\./g)` the `?` didn't use `\`?

Comment: @user001 I don't know what you mean, but I forgot to add a backslash there in front of the `?`. It is updated now.

Comment: @user001 I forgot to add a quantifier. =) Fixing it now.

Comment: @TLP Why do you prefer using `say` over `print`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6835/discussion-between-user001-and-tlp)

Answer (score 2):

In previous answer @TLP correctly wrote that matching should be in list context.

```
use Data::Dumper;

$text="?Adsfsadfgaasdf.
?Bafadfdsaa.
dsfadsf.
xcxvfdgfdg";

@arr = ($text =~ /\?([^\.]+\.)/g);

print Dumper(@arr);
```

Expected result:

```
$VAR1 = 'Adsfsadfgaasdf.';
$VAR2 = 'Bafadfdsaa.';
```

Comment: Dumper prefers to get references, try `print Dumper \@arr`.

Comment: I know, but for this example it does not matter

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `/g` flag, which tells perl to repeat the match as many times as possible.